# android webview video is not playing full screen mode

Tags: android, android-webview, android-video-player, android-websettings

i have to develop one android application.here the webvicw video is playing well..but if i have to click full screen mode means the video is crashes...how can i resolve these error...

How can i play video on full screen mode ??? or how can i play the video using youtube player ??? pls give me any suggestions ???

I have using below code:

```
content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
final Activity activity = this;
    content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
    public void onProgressChanged ( WebView view , int progress ){
        activity.setProgress(progress * 1000);
    }       
});

content.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onReceivedError ( WebView view , int errorCode , String description , String failingUrl ){
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Oh no! " + description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});

content.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

content.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
content.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
content.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, full_content, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it use **youtube player API**...these is easy one for android developer.it is played well on fullscreen mode.

Comment: And what exactly did you do? Can you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: yes already youtube app is downloading on ur device which means its working well on our app also...